# Selecting files by typing their name in Windows Explorer, and moving to the next matched file?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

When you open an Explorer window, you can focus on a file by starting to type its name. For example, if I have the following list of files, *sorted by type*:

`ABC.ini.bak`
`DEF.ini.bak`
`[... few hundred more .ini files ...]`
`ABC.ini`
`DEF.ini`

I could focus on "ABC.ini.bak" by typing "AB".

However, what if I actually want to select "ABC.ini", and not the ".bak" file?

Because it's sorted by *type*, I would have to scroll through hundreds of other files before reaching "ABC.ini" itself.

Is there a key which will allow me to jump to the "next match" when typing like this?

So I'd type "AB", it would focus on "ABC.ini.bak", then I'd hit [some key] and it'd focus on "ABC.ini" itself?

Comment: No such magical key or option AFAIK.

Comment: using the search feature of Windows 7 would be a much easier option, by searching for ABC*

Comment: @user13267: Of course. But that isn't really suitable for day-to-day browsing of files when you just want to open one quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I use the keyboard all the time to select files.

Depending on the names of the hundreds of other files between ABC.ini.bak and ABC.ini, you can do this:

Type ABC... (it selects ABC.ini.bak)... then pause a moment (~ 1 sec), then type ABC again... It should select the next "ABC"-named file... If the next "ABC" named file is ABC.ini, then it'll highlight.  (If you've got many other files starting with "ABC", then it'll have to go thru those first).

Comment: (I know OP was on Win7). I‘m on Win10 1903 and I could not figure out how the results were sorted when searching by just typing. It is not depending on the column I have currently sorted. Neither is it by filename nor by file type nor by last modified or another date I could pin it to. I know it is not random but to me as a user it feels random. I also get back to a file the explorer already selected before sometimes. This just feels buggy as hell.